# Teamcity - Unmet requirements: docker.server.osType contains windows

Tags: docker, teamcity

I installed Docker Desktop 2.0.0.3 on my Teamcity (build 61245) Build Agent and restarted the Build Agent/Server, I've also switch to run Windows containers but I am still getting

> Unmet requirements: docker.server.osType contains windows

Is this something I need to manually setup?

Docker plugin is installed and enabled by default in this build of Teamcity.

Comment: please provide more info. 1. about you configuration, 2. have you installed Docker Support plugin? 3. did you enable this plugin in your build configuration?

Comment: Docker plugin is installed and enabled by default in this version of Teamcity.

Comment: and answers for other question please

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by configuration. Do you mean my build step where I'm using Docker? I am trying to run yarn install in node:latest image. Specified in Run step within Docker container: node:latest. Docker image platform is set to Windows. Pull image explicitly is checked.

Comment: can you add to your question DSL of your configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a Teamcity bug where the docker.server.osType is not being set when running windows containers in Docker Desktop for Windows (Windows Server 2016).

My original setup, I had Docker running Windows containers in my Teamcity Server/Agent machine running Windows Server 2016. I was expecting to use Docker Wrapper and run Docker image platform set to Windows (I realized that would not work with the node image since that is built under the Linux platform). However, my docker.server.osType should still be set to windows regardless and I should have passed the compatibility check.

What I did to get around this was to run linux containers in my Windows Server 2016 machine. Below are the steps I took to address this issue.

- In the build agent, Docker Settings -> Daemon -> Check Experimental Features
- In the builder server {TeamCityDirectory}\conf\teamcity-startup.properties -> add *teamcity.docker.lcow.enabled = true*
- Switch docker to run linux containers

After doing that, I restarted my Build Agent and Build Server services, and the docker.server.osType in my Build Agent popped up to with value of linux. I then set my build step's Docker image platform to *linux*.

Comment: Just curious what you mean by "In the build agent". Is it in the TeamCity GUI or is it on the server itself?

Comment: Build agent is the the machine/process that handles the building process in TeamCity. TeamCity has a server process that serves the GUI and orchestrates the build agents.